# Probability that 2 out of 3 friends win a raffle?

Tags: probability, self-study, combinatorics

Let's say it's me and 2 other friends are at a raffle. There are 10 total participants. 3 of the 10 of us will win something, I don't care about what we win. A person can't win more than once. What is the probability that exactly two of us win something?

I'm thinking that the total outcomes is ${10 \choose 3}$ which is 120. But then the numerator I'm struggling. Would it be ${3 \choose 2} * 7$? If so, I'm confusing myself over it, so can someone please explain why this would/wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe the answer you seek. This result yields the probability of none of your group are winners.
$$
\frac{\binom{3}{0} \binom{7}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}
$$

This is the probability of one winning in your group, I think you can figure out the rest.

$$
\frac{\binom{3}{1} \binom{7}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}}
$$

Answer (score -2):

Numerator: 3C2
Denominator: 10C2

Comment: Can you explain how you got it?

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? We can also turn it into a comment.

Comment: So nos of ways any  2 contestants can win is 10C2, which will be denominator.

Comment: And you are 3 contestants and any 2 of them wining can happen in 3C2 ways, which will be numerator.

Comment: @tooshrit - but I think you have to factor in that you're choosing 3, not 2 people in the denominator.